# What is the correct maven dependency for Sikuli

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I have the following dependency in my pom.xml, but I am unable to use/improt Sikuli packages/classes in my project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That is the proper dependency according to https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-api/1.2.0/jar you have a different issue *somewhere*. Did you reimport the pom, do you have a working internet connection, can connect to the maven repo, etc.!?

Comment: I am seeing error at these import statements: import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

Comment: You did not answer any of the questions I asked.

Comment: Yes, I do have working internet connection and can connect to maven repository. All other dependencies are working fine except Sikuli. However, I don't see the errors when add the .jar file directly to the build path. I don't want to add it in build path as it takes the hard coded file path.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my issue:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sikulix/sikulixapi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am having error on the pom file after adding this dependency. But Class can be imported.